# Is this a correct Latin Translation for my businesses motto?

Tags: classical-latin, motto

It is supposed to read as "Be Professional, Be Firm, Be Sociable, Be Capable" which I got to be Lorem potest, stabiles estote, et Sociable, possit. Is this correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to the site! That translation you provided isn't quite correct, and I suspect you got it from Google Translate, which is notorious for jumbling words and other mistakes. Below is my attempt at translation. The one point of contention is whom you are addressing. Are you addressing a group of people (i.e. your employees as a whole) or a single person (i.e. each employee as an individual)? Since this is ostensibly a command, you can use either the singular imperative or a plural imperative of the verb *sum, esse*. These are *es* and *este*, respectively. You would also have to match the adjective to the verb (i.e. if you are talking to a group of people, you need a plural adjective). Finally, there's the matter of the grammatical gender to use for your employees. Typically masculine is used for persons of an unknown gender, so that is what I chose. Here's what I would propose depending on the way you take it:

> *Es Professionalis, Es Firmus, Es Communis, Es Potens*
>
> *Este Professionales, Este Firmi, Este Communes, Este Potentes*

Comment: The present imperatives are *es* in singular and *este* in plural. The future ones are *esto* and *estote*, respectively. (*Es* with long *e* is also the imperative "eat!" but there is hardly any chance of confusion here.)

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta You are correct, I misread a chart when I was checking myself. I will update accordingly!

Comment: This is for each individual employee to take to heart, but thank you for both options!